# How do I avoid webview zooming and improve its performance?

Tags: android

I have a js game code which I am showing in a webview. The code is defined such that it takes up the entire html page template, and when I pull it in a webview, I adjust the size accordingly.However, it zooms on double taps, which makes it difficult to play the game.How do I prevent it from zooming. Also, is there a way to speed up the performance, as the game is extremely slow and not ideal right now. 
Here's the code for the webview:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.setInitialScale(1);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webview.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
       // webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
       // webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.htm");
        //webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
        webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
```

Thanks,
Brian

My HTML Code bit :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        //meta data tag below 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,... etc>
            <title>Dino Dragon </title>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    </head>

    <body>
```

Comment: You mean it still zooms in even if you have called webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false)?

Comment: yeah, is there any way other to stop it from zooming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you placed in the beginning of your HTML document the following definition:

```
<meta name="viewport"
content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

This could prevent the webview from 'zooming in'.

Comment: that caused an issue where the images started overlapping and the view got reduced by 50dp on X and Y and upon double click was zoomable to full screen

Comment: So this declaration didn't stop the zooming?

Comment: no, i edited my question, showing how i used the meta data you suggested, also, i tried replacing the meta data in utf-8 with yours, but still no imrpovement, am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: the `<meta>` should be directly under `<html>` and not under `<head>` I think.

Comment: that worked. however, i am usign phonegap now and dont know how to add sound through javascript into the webview :\

Comment: Great! Sorry, I don't know how to add sound through phonegap but good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to extend a customized webview and override the onTouchEvent method.

And in the event callback, call setSupportZoom(false). Something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: I did, but still no luck

Comment: Modified another option. Please have a try.

Comment: can you explain programmatically, by editing your answer, i havent used ontouchevents before

Answer (score 0):

Use instead of
     webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); to

```
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
```